# Is it worth to use new operator in code optimization?

Tags: c++, optimization

I have two snippets of code. It seemed that the first snippet was slow

```
char*    ptrString = "Some string, maximum 4096 characters...";

size_t   sLen = strlen(ptrString);
WCHAR*   wchrText = new WCHAR[sLen+1];
size_t   i;
for(i=0; i<sLen; i++)
{
    if ( ptrString[i]=='A' ) break;
    wchrText[i] = ptrString[i];
}
//printf(wchrText);
```

I decided to remove `strlen` and `if`. Then the following snippet came to my mind

```
WCHAR*   wchrText = new WCHAR[4096];
size_t   i=0;
while(ptrString[i] != 'A')
{
    wchrText[i] = ptrString[i];
    i++;
}
//printf(wchrText);
```

Here i had to take wchrText, 4096 long. I was expecting to have a faster execution but there was not any sensible improve or i could not prove it! Is it the new operator in the second snippet which reduces speed? Is there any better solution?

Code syntax and the memory usage is not important.

Comment: There is no `new` operator in C

Comment: Why would you expect the second version to be faster? You're still doing the same comparison and the same copying of data.

Comment: How is that even supposed to compile? `printf()` takes a `char*`, but you're passing it a wide-char pointer.

Comment: Not to mention your second snippet will cause a buffer overrun if `ptrString` doesn't contain an `A`.

Comment: Also, what is `size_t   int i;` ?

Comment: It would help if you could describe what you're trying to accomplish; are you really intending to copy a (sub)string of *single-byte* characters to a string of *wide* characters?

Comment: Why do you hate null-terminated strings?

Comment: Thank you all. The code syntax is not important. The optimization method itself is the question. @Michael the first one has 2 comparisons while the second one has 1.

Comment: @Jango: The syntax *is* important. and your posted code is garbage. If you want to make a copy of a string, I recommend `strdup()`, if available.

Answer (score 0):

ahh you tricked me at first, the two loops should optimize to the same code depending on the compiler and settings of course, but there really isnt any difference.

one.c:

```
char*           ptrString = "Some string, maximum 4096 characters...";
unsigned int    sLen;
char            wchrText[4097];
int             i;

void one ( void )
{
    sLen = 4096;
    for(i=0; i<sLen; i++)
    {
        if ( ptrString[i]=='A' ) break;
        wchrText[i] = ptrString[i];
    }
}
```

two.c:

```
char*           ptrString = "Some string, maximum 4096 characters...";
unsigned int    sLen;
char            wchrText[4097];
int             i;

void two ( void )
{
    sLen = 4096;
    i=0;
    while(ptrString[i] != 'A')
    {
        wchrText[i] = ptrString[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

but they didnt.  one was a bit more code.  then I realized that your two loops are not equivalent.  the second loop does not have a limit check on the i variable, it can run past the length of the string through ram until it hits something it is not supposed to touch or finds that character.

so when I make the two examples the same:

one.c:

```
char*           ptrString = "Some string, maximum 4096 characters...";
unsigned int    sLen;
char            wchrText[4097];
int             i;

void one ( void )
{
    sLen = 4096;
    for(i=0; /*i<sLen*/; i++)
    {
        if ( ptrString[i]=='A' ) break;
        wchrText[i] = ptrString[i];
    }
}
```

I get the same exact code for each solution, as anticipated:

```
00000000 <one>:
   0:   e59f3044    ldr r3, [pc, #68]   ; 4c <one+0x4c>
   4:   e59f2044    ldr r2, [pc, #68]   ; 50 <one+0x50>
   8:   e59f0044    ldr r0, [pc, #68]   ; 54 <one+0x54>
   c:   e5931000    ldr r1, [r3]
  10:   e3a0ca01    mov ip, #4096   ; 0x1000
  14:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
  18:   e582c000    str ip, [r2]
  1c:   e5803000    str r3, [r0]
  20:   e5d12000    ldrb    r2, [r1]
  24:   e3520041    cmp r2, #65 ; 0x41
  28:   012fff1e    bxeq    lr
  2c:   e59fc024    ldr ip, [pc, #36]   ; 58 <one+0x58>
  30:   e7cc2003    strb    r2, [ip, r3]
  34:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
  38:   e5803000    str r3, [r0]
  3c:   e5f12001    ldrb    r2, [r1, #1]!
  40:   e3520041    cmp r2, #65 ; 0x41
  44:   1afffff9    bne 30 <one+0x30>
  48:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

although interesting if I fix the second function to match the first instead of the first to match the second

two.c:

```
char*           ptrString = "Some string, maximum 4096 characters...";
unsigned int    sLen;
char            wchrText[4097];
int             i;

void two ( void )
{
    sLen = 4096;
    i=0;
    while(ptrString[i] != 'A')
    {
        wchrText[i] = ptrString[i];
        i++;
        if(i<sLen) ; break;
    }
}
```

it does not optimize to the same code, still scratching my head on that one.

Comment: to do it the way you wanted with dynamically allocating the destination based on the length of the input string you need to use malloc() (and at some point free).  But since you know the length of the string has a max size you can just use that size.  I used globals here as an easy way to prevent the compiler from removing all of the code as dead code.

Comment: The disassembly of the two snippets would not be the same. The first snippet is using `strlen` function which has a loop to caculate the length. Definitly there is an 'A' in string. new operator is resolved to malloc internally by linker.

Comment: C does not have a new operator, if it is working for you that means that behind the scenes the C compiler is calling the C++ compiler (or more likely is both a C/C++ compiler) or you have done that specifically..

Comment: If you are trying to compare performance then that implies that in both cases the string has an A and if that is the case then optimize out the i<sLen check as it adds unecessary code.  If there is definitely that character in the string then yes the strlen and malloc are an unnecessary performance hit.

Comment: unless of course the code is written in a way that it just happens to optimize both out at compile time as your example code here might do depending on the compiler.

Comment: Thank you @dwelch for your replies. I'm using Microsoft compiler. The first snippet has a loop in `strlen` and another in the `for` in which there is a comparison. So 2 loops and 1 comparison. The second snippet has one loop for `while` and one comparison in it. So 1 loop and 1 comparison. Logically the second snippet should be faster but it seems not to be so. I think it is the overhead of `new WCHAR[4096]` that makes the second snippet to be like the first one.

Comment: the strlen takes you through the string twice, once for the strlen, then a second time to actually copy it, cheaper to just pass through that data once no matter how long it is.  the malloc (new) also costs as it has to do operating system/mmu stuff which is not free.  4K, unless on a microcontroller, is so small to be insignificant, not at all worth trying to play measuring and malloc games.  even if a local variable/array the allocation of the array is one instruction to subtract 4k from the stack pointer worst case.

Comment: then there are the loops which there is no reason to have them different (either both check the length or both dont) so that cost should be similar.  you could maybe try to find the character and then do a memcpy which depending on how deep could be a lot faster, but again it depends...get the strlen and malloc out of there in general though statically allocate the 4K. IMO

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the memory allocation and simply comparing loop performance, all things being equal, the second snippet will be faster by however much time an integer comparison takes.  Given no more than 4096 iterations, I doubt it will make a *measurable* difference on modern hardware.

***BUT***...

If you cannot guarantee that your source string will ***always, no exceptions***, contain an `'A'` character, then the second snippet is *extremely* unsafe, as you will overrun both the source and target arrays if the source does not contain an `'A'`.  Not to mention that you aren't properly terminating the target string.

You either need to keep the length check, or you need to look for the 0 terminator:

```
while ( ptrString[i] && ptrString[i] != 'A' )
   ...
```

Don't optimize away safety.

Comment: Thank you @JohnBode, the strings provided to the code are terminated to `A` . they are not ASCIIZ, they are ASCIIA ;)